How to prove that formula is not a tautology?
We have the following formalization of propositional logic with evaluation of formulas:
Require Import Classical.
Section Formula.
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Context {atom : Set}.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 5, at level 0).

Check fun p q => f_imp (f_imp (f_not (f_atom q)) (f_not (f_atom p))) (f_imp (f_atom p) (f_atom q)).
Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~(A -> ~B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) (A : formula) := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

Fixpoint eval (value : atom -> bool) (f : formula) : bool :=
  match f with
  | f_atom a => value a
  | f_not f => negb (eval value f)
  | f_imp f1 f2 => implb (eval value f1) (eval value f2)
end.

Definition tautology (f : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v f).

Definition contradictory (f : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, (eval v f) = false.

Definition logically_implies (A : formula) (B : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v A) -> is_true (eval v B).

Definition logically_equivalent (A : formula) (B : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, (eval v A) = (eval v B).

To prove a proposition that some formula us a tautology is simple: we unfold the definitions and try all the possible combinations of truth values for all the statement letters. If for any combination formula evaluates to true, it is a tautology. For example:
Proposition P1_3 (A B C: formula) : tautology $(A <-> (~B \/ C)) -> (~A -> B)$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology.
  intros.
  unfold is_true.
  simpl.
  destruct (eval v A), (eval v B), (eval v C) ; reflexivity.
Qed.

But how to prove that a formula is not a tautology? For example:
Proposition P1_4 (A B C: formula) (v : atom -> bool) : ~(tautology $(A -> (B \/ C)) \/ (A -> B)$).
Proof.
  unfold tautology.
  apply ex_not_not_all.

We get this state:
1 goal (ID 40)

  atom : Set
  A, B, C : formula
  v : atom -> bool
  ============================
  exists n : atom -> bool,
    ~ is_true (eval n $(A -> B \/ C) \/ (A -> B)$)

I found manually the values for A, B and C that make this formula false:
| A | B | C |
| T | F | F |

(1 -> (0 \/ 0) \/ (1 -> 0) = (1 -> 0) \/ 0 = 0 \/ 0 = 0

How can I construct such a function v that will return this combination of truth values to give it to exists?

Your Lemma is actually false. It currently says that the formula is never a tautology, independently of what A, B, or C are. But the formula is a tautology if e.g. B is always true.

@JoJoModding The Lemma is true. Look at the definition of tautology: a formula is a tautology is it is true for all the combinations of truth values for it's statement letters. And I transformed the goal to the following proposition: "there exists a tuple of values such that the formula is interpreted to false". I don't understand, how to provide the appropriate v : atom -> bool to give it to exists.

@user4305 it is false. See my answer.

Your Lemma is actually false. Here is a proof of False assuming that your lemma was true:
Proposition P1_4 (A B C: formula) (v : atom -> bool) : ~(tautology $(A -> (B \/ C)) \/ (A -> B)$).
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma foo : inhabited atom -> False.
Proof.
  intros [x].
  pose (tru := f_imp (f_atom x) (f_atom x)).
  pose (fals := f_not tru).
  pose proof (P1_4 fals tru tru (fun _ => true)) as H.
  (*                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ *)
  (* this argument is unnecessary, at is is unused in the Lemma statement itself. *)
  apply H.
  intros v. simpl. unfold is_true.
  destruct (v x); simpl; reflexivity.
Qed.

Note that the proof of False requires that there is an atom, because otherwise your whole theory becomes vacuous as no formulas would exist.

Something is not right. How can this theorem be false if I can present the values of A, B, C, such that the formula is evaluated to false? And therefore it is wrong that the formula is always true (is a tautology). Maybe, something is wrong with the definitions?

Because, as mentioned, proposition P1_4 says that something is never a tautology. "For any A, B, C, some formula using A, B, and C, is never a tautology" is how you read it aloud. Turns out that for some A, B, and C, it is a tautology.

"For any A, B, C, some formula using A, B, and C, is never a tautology" - I see now, How to say that the formula is not always a tautology?

Proposition P1_4 (A B C: formula) (v : atom -> bool) : exists A B C, ~(tautology $(A -> (B \/ C)) \/ (A -> B)$).?

I can't help you figure out what you want to prove here. I would guess that the lemma you want to actually state (and prove( is one where A, B, and C are distinct atoms instead of arbitrary propositions.

[This is a partial answer, but I hope it helps at least as a first approximation.]
One thing I find "suspect" in your code is that you mix equalities with implications in your definitions of tautology, contradictory, logically_implies and logically_equivalent.
That said, here are two theorems that are easy to prove and in the second one you can see how to instantiate a specific v:
Proposition P1_1 (A: formula) :
  tautology $~ ~ A <-> A$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology, is_true.
  intros v; cbn.
  destruct (eval v A); cbn.
  all: reflexivity.
Qed.

Proposition P1_2 (A: formula) :
  ~ tautology $(~ A <-> A)$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology, is_true.
  intros F.
  set (v := fun _ : atom => true).
  specialize (F v); cbn in F.
  destruct (eval v A); cbn in F.
  all: congruence.
Qed.

But I was not able to prove your P1_4, and I think that is for at least two reasons: 1) your atoms are completely opaque, so a v : atom -> bool cannot distinguish (match on) its input; and, 2) the following lemma is indeed false, since that A is not a tautology does not imply that ~ A is:
Lemma tautology_not (A: formula) :
  tautology $~ A$ <-> ~ tautology $A$.
Proof.
  unfold tautology, is_true.
  split; intros H.
  - intros G.
    set (v := fun _ : atom => true).
    specialize (H v); cbn in H.
    specialize (G v); cbn in G.
    rewrite G in H; cbn in H.
    congruence.
  - intros v.
    give_up.
Abort.


How to make atoms not opaque? This is the key to solution.

I am not in fact sure that is the key, since you have introduced atom_eq: but already you cannot say atom_eq a true, since true and false are not atoms...  Indeed, I look at your P1_4 and I too would think it must be true, possibly with some (clever?) use of classical axioms.  Anyway, just after defining eval, I'd write a bunch of lemmas that prove equivalence of different formulas, possibly up to supporting setoid-based rewriting, which you should indeed be able to achieve courtesy atom_eq.  Then I'd try to lift those results to properties in Prop...

P.S. Along the same line: << How to make atoms not opaque? >> Of course, as long as it is a classical logic, an easy one would be Definition atom := bool....

"just after defining eval, I'd write a bunch of lemmas that prove equivalence of different formulas, possibly up to supporting setoid-based rewriting" - can you give the definitions of these lemmas? I'll try to prove them.

The obvious ones, e.g. (in pseudo-code) $~~A<->A$ then $~~A$ <-> $A$ and similar: the point is breaking out of the $$ delimiters, "lifting to Prop".  But that is beyond your question (especially since you have already accepted an answer that is just negative), rather you have never said what logical theory exactly it is that you are trying to formalize, and why not just Definition atom := bool...?  --  Your P1_4 should of course be provable, the propositional statement (A -> (B \/ C)) \/ (A -> B) indeed is NOT a tautology, but your formalization is just not correct or sufficient...

"you have never said what logical theory exactly it is that you are trying to formalize" - the propositional calculus from the book "Introduction to mathematical logic" by Mendelson. Do you have it?

"why not just Definition atom := bool...?" - later I will be using "Formula" type as the basis for a formal theory with axioms (it is called a syntactic theory in Russia - I don't know how it is called in the West) and prove the theorems about it. The goal it to unite the semantic theory with an evaluator and syntactic theory with axioms and theorems with a theorem of completeness: every tautology is a theorem and every theorem is a tautology.

It is classical, I'll try bool.

[Amended] OK propositional, but the immediate distinguisher is classical or not. And, if it is a classical logic, you might just use bool as atom type, as that gives you not just decidability of (evaluation of) formulas, but full computability. Otherwise, you'd have to axiomatize properties of atoms/formulas to get the same effect, with the only added merit (maybe, I should see it to be sure) that it makes all the classical assumptions explicit... I'd invite you to a chat but I have been suspended from chatting: just take whatever you can from here and we'll see at your next question...
